# I want to display one error at a time with reactive forms with validator

Tags: angular, angular6, formgroups

How validate in order: v1,v2,v3 and display one error at a time.

```
this.form = this.formService.group({
  input1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
}, {
    validator: [(formGroup: FormGroup) => { return this.v1(formGroup) },
    (formGroup: FormGroup) => { return this.v2(formGroup) },
    (formGroup: FormGroup) => { return this.v3(formGroup) }]
  });
```

}

Is there any elegant way to make the validations done in order?
TNK!

Comment: Have your tried Combining your validator functions into one function which calls the right order?

Comment: I agree with @KhaledShaaban create a custom validator and return what you want when you want to.